# How to notify crawler that ajax powered page is completely loaded and ready to take snapshot

Tags: angularjs, ajax, bots, google-crawlers, web-search

There are Angular/REST powered web pages, but with no navigation module being used (no hash based (#!) navigation).
Despite deprecating of google's ajax-crawling [webmasters-ajax-crawling](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started), it seems crawler only sees that JS generated content which does not rely on AJAX (REST) calls responses, and does not see page content which is depends on AJAX calls response.

It feels like google does not give enough time for a page to render, since it has no ability to identify if all expected logic in JS has finished completelly..

Q: is there a way to tell google (and to an abstract browser in general) that page completely rendered and no pending AJAX calls are there?
May be someone can suggest how to avoid rendering of page by angular - until all AJAX calls are completed (perhaps something like customized ng-cloak)?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question..

- It was asked because: it seemed that google failed to index text from
  pages which is rendered by angular, after AJAX calls were performed.
- Now: I see that google crawler actually indexes everything, so - no
  need to notify crawler that page was rendered - it can recognize this
  by itself.
- But: I think google indexes pages in two phases: 1. Quickly indexing HTML of a page with no JS rendering involved (just after main document was fetched); 2. Performs heavy operation of rendering page with JS and indexes all rendered content. Second step may happen couple days after first one, so that's why you may see no indexed content for a while..